# Why is my Java range slider not able to slide both thumbs at once?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jslider, rangeslider

I am currently trying to implement a feature in this range slider where the user can click the space in between the upper thumb and lower thumb then drag to move both thumbs at once to update the range values. These are the classes I am working with:

RangeSlider.java: https://pastebin.com/APxuaEwP

RangeSliderUI.java: https://pastebin.com/aUy7cLni

RangeSliderDemo.java: https://pastebin.com/BNLzxNtJ

I have implemented components in the RangeTrackListener in RangeSliderUI.java that serve to move both thumbs when the user drags the space between. Here is the RangeTrackListener with changes made:

```
 /**
 * Listener to handle mouse movements in the slider track.
 */
public class RangeTrackListener extends TrackListener {
    private boolean windowSliding;
    private double previousY;

    private void updateRectanglesForSlidingWindow(MouseEvent e) {
        if(windowSliding) {
            double diff = previousY - e.getY();
            int upperThumbRectNewY = (int) Math.floor(upperThumbRect.getY() - diff);
            int thumbRectNewY = (int) Math.floor(thumbRect.getY() - diff);
            if(upperThumbRectNewY < yPositionForValue(slider.getMaximum()) && thumbRectNewY > yPositionForValue(slider.getMinimum())) {
                upperThumbRect.setLocation((int) Math.floor(upperThumbRect.getX()), upperThumbRectNewY);
                thumbRect.setLocation((int) Math.floor(thumbRect.getX()), thumbRectNewY);
                previousY = e.getY();
                slider.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateValuesForSlidingWindow(MouseEvent e) {
        if(windowSliding) {
            /*double diff = previousY - e.getY();
            int upperThumbRectNewY = (int)Math.floor(upperThumbRect.getY() - diff);
            int thumbRectNewY = (int)Math.floor(thumbRect.getY() - diff);
            upperThumbRect.setLocation((int)Math.floor(upperThumbRect.getX()), upperThumbRectNewY);
            thumbRect.setLocation((int)Math.floor(thumbRect.getX()), thumbRectNewY);*/
            double prevVal = slider.getValue();
            double newVal = valueForYPosition((int)Math.floor(thumbRect.getY()));
            double valDiff = prevVal - newVal;
            slider.setValue((int)Math.floor(newVal));
            slider.setExtent((int)Math.floor(slider.getExtent() - valDiff));
            windowSliding = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!slider.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        currentMouseX = e.getX();
        currentMouseY = e.getY();

        if(currentMouseY > thumbRect.getY() && !thumbRect.contains(0, currentMouseY) && currentMouseY < upperThumbRect.getY() && !upperThumbRect.contains(0, currentMouseY)) {
            windowSliding = true;
            previousY = currentMouseY;
        }

        if (slider.isRequestFocusEnabled()) {
            slider.requestFocus();
        }

        // Determine which thumb is pressed.  If the upper thumb is
        // selected (last one dragged), then check its position first;
        // otherwise check the position of the lower thumb first.
        boolean lowerPressed = false;
        boolean upperPressed = false;
        if (upperThumbSelected || slider.getMinimum() == slider.getValue()) {
            if (upperThumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                upperPressed = true;
            } else if (thumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                lowerPressed = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (thumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                lowerPressed = true;
            } else if (upperThumbRect.contains(currentMouseX, currentMouseY)) {
                upperPressed = true;
            }
        }

        // Handle lower thumb pressed.
        if (lowerPressed) {
            switch (slider.getOrientation()) {
                case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                    offset = currentMouseY - thumbRect.y;
                    break;
                case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                    offset = currentMouseX - thumbRect.x;
                    break;
            }
            upperThumbSelected = false;
            lowerDragging = true;
            return;
        }
        lowerDragging = false;

        // Handle upper thumb pressed.
        if (upperPressed) {
            switch (slider.getOrientation()) {
                case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                    offset = currentMouseY - upperThumbRect.y;
                    break;
                case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                    offset = currentMouseX - upperThumbRect.x;
                    break;
            }
            upperThumbSelected = true;
            upperDragging = true;
            return;
        }
        upperDragging = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        updateValuesForSlidingWindow(e);
        lowerDragging = false;
        upperDragging = false;
        slider.setValueIsAdjusting(false);
        super.mouseReleased(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        updateRectanglesForSlidingWindow(e);
        if (!slider.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        currentMouseX = e.getX();
        currentMouseY = e.getY();

        if (lowerDragging) {
            slider.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
            moveLowerThumb();

        } else if (upperDragging) {
            slider.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
            moveUpperThumb();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldScroll(int direction) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Moves the location of the lower thumb, and sets its corresponding
     * value in the slider.
     */
    protected void moveLowerThumb() {
        int thumbMiddle = 0;

        switch (slider.getOrientation()) {
            case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                int halfThumbHeight = thumbRect.height / 2;
                int thumbTop = currentMouseY - offset;
                int trackTop = trackRect.y;
                int trackBottom = trackRect.y + (trackRect.height - 1);
                int vMax = yPositionForValue(slider.getValue() + slider.getExtent());

                // Apply bounds to thumb position.
                if (drawInverted()) {
                    trackBottom = vMax;
                } else {
                    trackTop = vMax;
                }
                thumbTop = Math.max(thumbTop, trackTop - halfThumbHeight);
                thumbTop = Math.min(thumbTop, trackBottom - halfThumbHeight);

                setThumbLocation(thumbRect.x, thumbTop);

                // Update slider value.
                thumbMiddle = thumbTop + halfThumbHeight;
                slider.setValue(valueForYPosition(thumbMiddle));
                break;

            case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
                int thumbLeft = currentMouseX - offset;
                int trackLeft = trackRect.x;
                int trackRight = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - 1);
                int hMax = xPositionForValue(slider.getValue() + slider.getExtent());

                // Apply bounds to thumb position.
                if (drawInverted()) {
                    trackLeft = hMax;
                } else {
                    trackRight = hMax;
                }
                thumbLeft = Math.max(thumbLeft, trackLeft - halfThumbWidth);
                thumbLeft = Math.min(thumbLeft, trackRight - halfThumbWidth);

                setThumbLocation(thumbLeft, thumbRect.y);

                // Update slider value.
                thumbMiddle = thumbLeft + halfThumbWidth;
                slider.setValue(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle));
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Moves the location of the upper thumb, and sets its corresponding
     * value in the slider.
     */
    protected void moveUpperThumb() {
        int thumbMiddle = 0;

        switch (slider.getOrientation()) {
            case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                int halfThumbHeight = thumbRect.height / 2;
                int thumbTop = currentMouseY - offset;
                int trackTop = trackRect.y;
                int trackBottom = trackRect.y + (trackRect.height - 1);
                int vMin = yPositionForValue(slider.getValue());

                // Apply bounds to thumb position.
                if (drawInverted()) {
                    trackTop = vMin;
                } else {
                    trackBottom = vMin;
                }
                thumbTop = Math.max(thumbTop, trackTop - halfThumbHeight);
                thumbTop = Math.min(thumbTop, trackBottom - halfThumbHeight);

                setUpperThumbLocation(thumbRect.x, thumbTop);

                // Update slider extent.
                thumbMiddle = thumbTop + halfThumbHeight;
                slider.setExtent(valueForYPosition(thumbMiddle) - slider.getValue());
                break;

            case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
                int thumbLeft = currentMouseX - offset;
                int trackLeft = trackRect.x;
                int trackRight = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - 1);
                int hMin = xPositionForValue(slider.getValue());

                // Apply bounds to thumb position.
                if (drawInverted()) {
                    trackRight = hMin;
                } else {
                    trackLeft = hMin;
                }
                thumbLeft = Math.max(thumbLeft, trackLeft - halfThumbWidth);
                thumbLeft = Math.min(thumbLeft, trackRight - halfThumbWidth);

                setUpperThumbLocation(thumbLeft, thumbRect.y);

                // Update slider extent.
                thumbMiddle = thumbLeft + halfThumbWidth;
                slider.setExtent(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle) - slider.getValue());
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

It produces strange behavior like the following:

[image: strange behavior]

I am wondering if I am misunderstanding the use of the valueForYposition function. I have been banging my head on this for a little while now. I feel as if I am missing something obvious. I wish I could ask a more specific question regarding this code. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look and enlighten me on any obvious mistakes. Thank you very much.

EDIT: The issue has been resolved. I was being naive with regards to how the setValue function worked in this implementation of RangeSlider. Thank you to all who took a look.

Comment: Unfortuantely, that is a lot of code to be looked at and it doesn't compile.  Have you been putting in print statements to track values when you drag it one way vs the other?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [mre]